# How can I properly connect my React Native application to a Firebase Emulator Suite?

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have been working on a react native application using a bare workflow. I have a Firebase project set up with Authentication and a Realtime Database which is already working with the app using live resources. I am currently trying to incorporate Cloud Functions, so I am setting up a Firebase Emulator Suite to test the Cloud Functions and Realtime Database without affecting production resources. I have just initialized the Firebase Emulator and have gotten the helloWorld template function to work locally when placing the function url in a browser.

The issue is that when implementing the Firebase Emulator resources, I am getting this error for the emulator database calls:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).`

I am also using native modules in iOS, testing on an iOS device, and I have done no further network configuration on the device.

Here are relevant files for the local Firebase setup:
firebase.json

```json
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

index.js

```js
/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
 * const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 */

const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Here is the relevant firebaseConfig.js used in the React Native application for any Firebase call.

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, connectDatabaseEmulator} from "firebase/database";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "HIDDEN",
  authDomain: "HIDDEN",
  projectId: "HIDDEN",
  storageBucket: "HIDDEN",
  messagingSenderId: "HIDDEN",
  appId: "HIDDEN",
  databaseURL: "HIDDEN"
};

/* Production and Emulator Firebase configs */

// Production: Initialize Firebase App
const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const FIREBASE_DB = getDatabase(FIREBASE_APP);
const FIREBASE_AUTH = getAuth(FIREBASE_APP);

connectAuthEmulator(FIREBASE_AUTH, "http://localhost:9099");
connectDatabaseEmulator(FIREBASE_DB, "localhost", 9000);

export { FIREBASE_APP, FIREBASE_DB, FIREBASE_AUTH };
```

I am sure the ports are not an issue, although I am not sure about the localhost ip address being used. I have tested the firebaseConfig.js with the following ips: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

I have tried using `connectAuthEmulator` and `connectDatabaseEmulator` in every RN file that calls `FIREBASE_DB` or `FIREBASE_AUTH`. I have also tried setting the databaseURL in the firebaseConfig to match the emulator database url.